# PHP debugging configuration

Tags: php, macos, xampp, phpstorm

When trying to configure XDebug in XAMPP on OS X to connect back to PHPStorm receiving the following messages in the xdebug log and fails to stop at the breakpoint in PHPStorm.  Any hints on what to try next?

Xdebug.log

```
Log opened at 2015-10-16 21:36:56
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Remote address found, connecting to ::1:9002.
I: Connected to client. 
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/eatdata/app/php/crops/getCropTypes.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="23586" idekey="PHPSTORM"><engine version="2.2.5"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2014 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 2 -n max_depth -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 3 -n max_children -v 100
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

<- status -i 4
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="4" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

<- step_into -i 5
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="5" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 6 -t line -f file:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/eatdata/app/php/connect.php -n 71
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="6"><error code="5"><message><![CDATA[command is not available]]></message></error></response>
```

Believe this line in particular indicates the problem but not sure what exactly this message means.

```
<response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="6">
<error code="5">
<message><![CDATA[command is not available]]></message>
</error>
</response>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "command is not available" line is likely there because you have a typo/syntax error somewhere in `http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/eatdata/app/php/crops/getCropTypes.php` - can you run `php -l` against it to find out?

I can also see a problem because of case-sensitivity in filenames. OS/PHP sometimes reports a different caseness for files than your editor expects. I see you are using version 2.2.5, and I would therefore suggest you upgrade to at least 2.3.0, as that has this issue fixed.